# How to find files whose names contain any of 2 strings?

Tags: linux, search

I'd like to find files whose name contain "Mar" or "Jun", how can I do this?

Comment: find . -type f -name "Mar" -name "Jun"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first approach (`find . -type f -name "Mar" -name "Jun"`) had two problems:

- `find` combines different rules using a logical "and" by default
- You did an exact name match

So the only possible matches were *files* that were named *exactly* "Jun" *and* "Mar", i.e. none.

---

Instead, do the following:

- You can use wildcards in the name search (`*` means any possibly empty sequence of characters), wrapped in quotation marks to prevent interpretation by the shell
- combine the two rules with an `-o` (*or*) — this requires you two wrap the alternative rules in parentheses to override usual operator precedence, or to repeat the common `-type f` rule

Example:

```
$ ls -1
1st-of-June
January
March
$ find . -type f -name '*Mar*' -o -type f -name '*Jun*'
./1st-of-June
./March
```

Comment: Thanks, how about this: How can I find files that contains 2 strings together, the strings may or may not be on the same line. And what if I want to find files which satisfy this condition and also created after a specific date?

Comment: @alwbtc Please clarify, your original question stated you were looking for files with a specific name? Was that not correct, or are you now asking something totally different?

Comment: Yes, that was correct, and you answered it. Now I would like to know how to do this other search? Could you please?

Comment: @alwbtc How about you try it yourself first? The date restriction is really easy with what you learned from the answers to this question and a tiny bit of reading `man find`. The other part can be solved using `find -exec` and the `grep` program.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` and its `regex` option:

```
find -regex '.*\(Mar\|Jun\).*'
```

Comment: If you use `-regextype posix-extended`, you won't have to escape the brackets and pipe with a `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *{Jun,Mar}*
```

This lists all the filenames that contain Jun or Mar

Answer (score 0):

This command will work

```
[max@localhost ~]$ find / -type f -name Mar -o -name Jun
./Mar
./Jun
```

**UPDATE**

Then this is the answer

```
find / -type f -name "*Mar*" -o -type f -name "*Jun*"
```

Comment: This returns folders named `Jun`, and misses files named `June` or `March`.